# Autocompletion doesn't work via ssh

Tags: ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
For some reasons when I use ssh connection autocompletion with ros-commands doesn't work. On the original computer tab completion works, but when I connect to it via ssh I cannot use tab completion :(

I have "source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash" in my .bashrc

I get the following error, after writing roscd [+tab]

> roscd terminate called after throwing
> an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
> what():
> locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name
> not valid terminate called after
> throwing an instance of
> 'std::runtime_error' what():
> locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name
> not valid

Anyone had the same problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72211/autocompletion-doesn%27t-work-via-ssh/) by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2013-08-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okey, the answer is here (written by KruseT):
http://answers.ros.org/question/53353/autocomplete-not-working-anymore/?comment=72208#comment-72208

ANSWER

> export LC_ALL="C" maybe put it in your
> .bashrc

---

Originally posted by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) with karma: 306 on 2013-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jmainpri](https://answers.ros.org/users/4656/jmainpri/) on 2015-12-07**:
got a similar error for rospack profile with export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"